# calculate limit with definite integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I need to calculate this limit

$\lim_{x\to 0}1/x$$\int_0^x [ln(t+2)/t^2+1] \,dt$

I took the integral:

$I = \int_0^x [ln(t+2)/t^2+1] \,dt$ = $\int_0^x ln(t+2)argctg'(t) \,dt$ = $arctg(x)ln(x+2)$ - $\int_0^x [arctg(t)/t+2] \,dt$

But I don't know how to approach this furthermore.

Comment: By Fundamental Theorem of Calculus the desired limit equals the value of integrand at $0$ ie $\log 2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply L'Hopital rule.
$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\dfrac{\int\limits_0^x\dfrac{\ln(t+2)}{t^2+1}dt}{x}\right)=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\dfrac{\ln(x+2)}{x^2+1}\right)=\boxed{\ln2}$$

Comment: Thank you... Of course, if you have an integral, and you applied the L'Hopital, you will get the function from the integral

Comment: Why the numerator is 0? Such that we have 0/0 for l'Hopital

Comment: @Akhtubir, the numerator tends to zero because the value of a definite integral is zero when both the limits of integration are same.